# How to access a column whose name I cannot access in chained operations

Tags: python, pandas

I'll preface this by saying this is a toy example - I do have motivations for doing this, as it sits in the middle of some other chained operations.

I have a DataFrame something like

```
df
Out[234]: 
            host1  host2  host3
dates                          
2014-02-02      1      3      4
2014-02-03      5      2      1
2014-02-04      2      5      6
2014-02-05      4      6      1
2014-02-06      3      2      1
```

I am trying to produce a new DataFrame consisting of two columns with the hosts being the index - one column being the values in the last row, the second being whether those values in the last row are greater than 1. My corresponding output should then look like:

```
newdf
Out[235]: 
dates           2014-02-06  passes
host1                    3    True
host2                    2    True
host3                    1   False
```

**How can I do this with chained operations?**

---

Accomplishing the output in and of itself is pretty easy I think, I just did

```
newdf = df.tail(1).T
newdf['passes'] = newdf.iloc[:, 0] > 1
```

The reason I'm struggling mightily to do it with chained operations is because as soon as I transpose the tail, the column name becomes of type `pandas.tslib.Timestamp`,

```
df.tail(1).T
Out[236]: 
dates  2014-02-06
host1           3
host2           2
host3           1
```

which I can't seem to access to rename with `rename`, and so I then can't access it in some boolean operation in `assign` to create the new "passes" column.

**Data**:

My toy DataFrame can be generated with

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(dates=pd.date_range('2014-02-02', periods=5),
                       host1=[1, 5, 2, 4, 3], 
                       host2=[3, 2, 5, 6, 2], 
                       host3=[4, 1, 6, 1, 1])).set_index('dates')
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `lambda` expression in `assign`, where the parameter is the result from previous chained operation:

```
df.tail(1).T.assign(passes = lambda x: x.iloc[:,0] > 1)

#dates  2014-02-06 00:00:00 passes
#host1                    3   True
#host2                    2   True
#host3                    1  False
```

Comment: Well, you have to see it firstly before you can think of it, I guess. :)

Answer (score 7):

you can try this:

```
In [110]: df.tail(1).T.assign(passes=df.tail(1).values[0] > 1)
Out[110]:
dates  2014-02-06 00:00:00 passes
host1                    3   True
host2                    2   True
host3                    1  False
```

Comment: This is nice too - for some reason I didn't think that `tail` was so cheap, but testing it it sure seems to be.

Comment: @EricHansen, i'd choose Psidom's solution - it's much more elegant ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I want to leave a comment to Psidom solution and not post a new solution (but cant leave comments yet due to not enough reputation). This one works too

```
df.tail(1).T.assign(passes = lambda x: x.gt(1))
```